# How can I make this JS function shorter?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm currently using this script to hide elements by their ID numbers:

```js
function items() {

var div = document.getElementById('QTDItems');
var itensQtd = div.textContent;

if (itensQtd == 1) {
    for(var i=2; i<=20; i++){
        var element = document.getElementById("item"+i);
            element.style.display = 'none';
    }
} 

else if (itensQtd == 2) {
    for(var i=3; i<=20; i++){
        var element = document.getElementById("item"+i);
            element.style.display = 'none';
    }
} 
// And so on until the else if (itensQtd == 18)
```

I'm using the `itensQtd = div.textContent` because I'm scaping a PHP variable to the html like this:

```
<div id="QTDItems" style="display: block;">
    <?php echo block_field('exame-qtd'); ?>
</div>
```

But for every one of the 20 divs I have to create an IF that selects which ID numbers will be hidden. I'm not that good with JavaScript yet, so I don't know how to make it shorter and smarter. Can someone help?

Comment: `for (var i = itensQtd + 1; i <= 20; i++) {` ??

Comment: `var startIndex = parseInt(itensQtd) + 1;` should get you on your way

Comment: why not start with hiding all items?

Comment: `Number(itensQtd) + 1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function HideItems(itensQtd){
    for(var i=itensQtd+1; i<=20; i++){
        var element = document.getElementById("item"+i);
            element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

or you can use the arrow function:

```
HideItems = (itensQtd) => {
    for(var i=itensQtd+1; i<=20; i++){
        var element = document.getElementById("item"+i);
            element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Note: it is best to replace the number in the condition `"i<=20"` with the total number of divs found.

Then you call it like this. No need to call **if** conditional:

```
var div = document.getElementById('QTDItems');
var itensQtd = div.textContent;
HideItems(itensQtd);
```

Answer (score -2):

Alright, there's a lot of things wrong here. You should definitely check out a JavaScript tutorial on Youtube or on other resources like [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). First off, you should use let/const instead of var. So whenever you want to create a variable, you use `let`, like this:

```
let itensQtd = div.textContent;
```

or this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

You also need to properly parse the text content and make sure it's a number.

```
const goalID = parseInt(div.textContent);
```

When it comes to your question, you can create a loop that iterates on each of the elements and sets them to none unless it's the element you want to display.

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
   const element = document.getElementById(`item ${i}`);
   if(i === goalID) element.style.display = 'block'; // not sure how you want to display the one that you don't want to hide.
   else element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Overall, this will fix the problem stated, but you should definitely try to do a modern JavaScript tutorial to learn the basics. Not sure what your bigger project is, but there is definitely a problem if you need to find which element to hide/display by parsing the text content of another element.